# Android sqlite db load data to server and truncate

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization

I have written an app that saves some data in sqlite db. Periodically I want to send this data to server and then truncate the tables in sqlite (so that the app does not fill up the space on device).

I am using singleton object of SQLiteOpenHelper (which I have read is thread safe).

So my question is - does the following code looks ok-

```
SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper = MyDBOpenHelper.getInsance();
SQLiteDatabase database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
database.beginTransaction();
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(SELECT_ALL_TABLE1_STMT, null);

while( cursor.moveToNext()) {
  // save result in tmp list/buffer
}

database.execSQL(DELETE_ALL_TABLE1_STMT);
database.endTransaction();
database.setTransactionSuccessful();

// send data to server
// and repeat the process for rest of the tables.
```

If there is another thread that is trying to write to the same table (that I am reading and later will truncate), then does the above code looks ok to handle that scenario?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need more input on this from here:

- [Synchronized Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)
- [Android Multi-threading](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html)

Plus AsyncTask, of course.

Comment: I am not sure, if I followed your answer correctly. My getInstance() function is synchronized. And my code does not have any activity. It is a service running in background. So I think I don't need AsyncTask. As far as inserts are concerned, a thread gets instance of SQLiteOpenHelper and runs insert statement.

Comment: What you need is make it possible the changes in the table (truncate or whatever) to happen only from one thread? If so, sychronized methods will help and also read the Android Multi-threading articles.